# Is it redundant to have わかるようになる and つもり in the same sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is it redundant to have わかるようになる and つもり in the same sentence?

For example: このノートの目標は、日本語ノートをきれいに書くのではなって、本当に学習をわかるようになるつもりです。

Likewise, is the rest of the sentence content correct?

Comment: I am not sure why you feel it may be redundant to have both わかるようになる and つもり, so I can't answer. As a native speaker, the part「日本語ノートをきれいに書くのではなって」seems awkward. Do you mean to say that "Not only writing down Japanese to the note beautifully," or something like that?  and it connects to the main part of your question "but also trying to understand the language very well."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying both ようになる and つもりです is fine. They mean different things, so it is not redundant.

But you have to match the subject and the object. 目標は～つもりです literally translates to "The objective intends to ～" or "My purpose is going to ～", which does not make sense because the objective itself does not have a will.

Instead, you have to say either of the following:

- 目標は～することです "The objective is to ～"
- (私は)～するつもりです " I am going to ～" "I intend to ～"

In addition, 学習を分かる is ungrammatical. You don't say "to understand learning" in English, either.

> - このノートの目標は、日本語でノートをきれいに書くことではなく、学習したことが本当に理解できるようになることです。
> - 単に日本語でノートをきれいに書くのではなく、本当に分かるようになるつもりです。